# Matching tokens carrying values with Scala's parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have a type of tokens that I want to parse using Scala's `util.parsing.combinator.Parsers`. My token
class looks something like this:

```
abstract class Token ()

case class T_Semicolon () extends Token {} // represents ;                                                                                                                            
case class T_LeftBracket () extends Token {} // represents (                                                                                                                          
....                                                                                                          
case class T_Identifier ( s : String ) extends Token {}
case class T_Integer ( n : Int ) extends Token {}
```

I would like to construct a Scala parser with the usual `~ ~> <~ | ...` combinators
as follows.

```
object StandAloneParser extends Parsers {

   import Token._
   override type Elem = Token

   val prog = rep1 ( dec )
   val dec = T_Def () ~> T_Identifier ( id ) ~ ...
```

However the pattern matching doesn't allow me to match `T_Identifier ( id )` because the variable
`id` is not declared. Who can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't very clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
lazy val identifier: Parser[String] =
  acceptMatch("identifier", { case T_Identifier(id) => id })
```

Also notice that I'm using `lazy val` rather than just `val`. Since parsers tend to have a lot of interdependencies, and might even be recursive, this is typically a good idea.

You'd then use that `identifier` parser in your `dec` parser:

```
lazy val dec = T_Def () ~> identifier ~ ...
```

Comment: @MartinBerger - Your example won't compile as shown because you reference `dec` in `prog` before `dec` is declared. Using `def` instead of `val` solves this problem—but using `lazy val` is better if you want to cache the parser results.